# Libre Office Base: Unable to change or save records in form

Tags: libreoffice, records, designmode

I am working with LibreOffice Base and I've made a form to insert data in my table, but when I open this form ( not in Design-mode, just right-mouse click and select 'Open' ), I am able to view the existing records, but I am not able to change and save the records.

[image: My problem]

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can I suggest that you add an answer to your own question, and then mark that as the accepted answer? It makes it clearer that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables in LibreOffice Base need a primary key. Only then you can change and save records.